# How to get a vector from an array in R

Tags: r, arrays, vector

I'm sorry I don't know exactly how to word this question. Basically, I have an array of x and y coordinates called `mydata` that looks like this:

```
              x        y
  [1,]       12        1
  [2,]       13        2
  [3,]      NaN      NaN
  [4,]      NaN      NaN
  [5,]       64        5
```

`dput(mydata)` gives:

```
structure(c(12, 13, 
NaN, NaN, 64 ... .Dim = c(934L, 
2L, 2L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("x", "y"), NULL, NULL))
```

`str(mydata)` gives:

```
num [1:934, 1:2, 1:2, 1:3] 558 NaN NaN NaN NaN ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 4
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:2] "x" "y"
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : NULL
```

I want to input this data into a function, `f(x, y)` , that takes two vectors (x and y). How can I input this data into the function? My instinct is to do  `f(mydata['x'], mydata['y']`, but that's not working.

Comment: Your structure is giving me error.  Can you show the `str(mydata)`

Comment: Do you have a data like `mydata <- array(1:40, dim = c(5, 2, 2, 2), dimnames = list(NULL, c("x", "y"), NULL, NULL))` and want to extract all the 'x', 'y' columns?

Comment: Yes, I would like the extract the x and y columns from this array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a `4D` array, try

```
f(c(mydata[, "x", ,]),  c(mydata[, "y", ,]))
```

#### data

```
mydata <- array(1:40, dim = c(5, 2, 2, 2), 
   dimnames = list(NULL, c("x", "y"), NULL, NULL))
```

Comment: When I try to view mydata[, "x"] I'm getting this error message: ```Error in mydata[, "x"] : incorrect number of dimensions```

Comment: @11thal11thal This is based on the example you showed.  It seems to be `matrix`.  Can you update your post with the `dput(mydata)` or `str(mydata)`

Comment: Done -- when I check the class of the data it says array

Comment: @11thal11thal please show the `str(mydata)` as your structure is incomplete and gives error

Comment: @11thal11thal class can be both matrix and array i.e. `class(matrix(1:25, 5, 5))#
[1] "matrix" "array"`

Comment: @11thal11thal please see my update. thanks

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help!